# Proving the first Weyl Algebra is a domain and $\mathrm{Z}(A_1)=\Bbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, noncommutative-algebra

We [define](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411603/on-the-first-weyl-algebra) the **first Weyl Algebra** $A_1$ as the ring of all linear differential operators with polynomial coefficients. That is,
$$A_1=A_1(\Bbb C):=\{a_n(X) \delta^n+\dotsb+a_1(X)\delta+a_0(X):a_i(X)\in\Bbb C[X],\in \Bbb N \}\subseteq \mathrm{End}_\Bbb C(\Bbb C[X]),$$
where $\delta:=\frac{d}{dX}$.
We assume that we know the *Leibniz's Rule*
$$\delta^n \circ x^m= x^m \circ \delta^n + \lambda_{m-1}x^{m-1} \delta^{m-1}+\lambda_{m-2}x^{m-2} \delta^{m-2}+\dotsb$$ we want to prove the following properties:

1. $A_1$ is a domain.
2. The center of $A_1$ is $\mathrm Z (A_1)=\Bbb C$.

*My attempt.* 1. We take $\alpha:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i(X)\delta^i,\beta:=\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_j(X)\delta^j \in A_1$, which are not zero. Thus, we can assume that $a_n(X),b_m(X)\neq 0$. Then, if 
$$\alpha \circ \beta =0 \iff a_n(X)b_m(X)\delta^{n+m}+\text{lower order terms}=0.$$
Since the set $\{x^i\circ \delta^j:0\leq i,j \leq \infty\}$ is a basis, we obtain that $a_n(X),b_m(X)=0$, so we have a contradiction.

2. As we know, 
   $\mathrm{Z}(A_1)=\{\alpha \in A_1: \alpha \circ \rho=\rho \circ \alpha,\ \forall \rho \in A_1\}$. We want to show that $\mathrm{Z}(A_1)=\Bbb C$. Let's take a non-zero element $\alpha:=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i(X)\delta^i$ with $a_n(X)\neq 0$. My idea is to show that if $n\geq 1$, then $\alpha \circ x - x\circ \alpha \neq 0$. But I don't know how to apply it.

**Questions.** 1) Is 1. correct?

2) What about 2.? Could you please write an elaborate proof? I couldn't find much stuff about this notion.

*Thank you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Looks correct. I suppose you could be more explicit about how you got the leading term you got, depending on the reader. (Also pet peeve of mine: the letter $m$ comes before $n$ in the alphabet.)

(2) Suppose $\alpha$ commutes with $\delta$. Subtract out all leading terms with constant coefficients until you get an expression $\overline{\alpha}=a_k(x)\delta^k+a_{k-1}(x)\delta^{k-1}+\cdots$. Suppose $k\ge1$. Then writing $\delta\overline{\alpha}=\overline{\alpha}\delta$ gives

$$ a_k(x)\delta^{k+1}+[\delta a_k(x)+a_{k-1}(x)]\delta^k+\cdots=a_k(x)\delta^{k+1}+a_{k-1}(x)\delta^k+\cdots $$

Equating coefficients of $\delta^k$ gives $\delta a_k(x)=0$, so $a_k(x)$ is constant, a contradiction. Therefore $k=0$, in which case $\delta\overline{\alpha}=\overline{\alpha}\delta$ implies $a_0(x)$ is constant too. Thus, $\alpha$ is purely a polynomial in $\delta$ with constant coefficients.

Writing $\alpha=\sum_j a_j\delta^j$ and $x^{\ell}\alpha=\alpha x^{\ell}$ I'll let you figure out why $\alpha$ can't contain any $\delta$s. (Pick $\ell$.)

Comment: Dear runway44, thank you for your answer. Could you please explain the point where you write "Subtract out all leading terms with constant coefficients until you get an expression"?

Comment: @Chris For example suppose $\alpha=\delta^n+x\delta^{n-1}+\cdots$. The leading coefficient $a_n(x)=1$ is a constant (with respect to $x$), so subtract $\delta^n$ from $\alpha$ to get $\overline{\alpha}=x\delta^{n-1}+\cdots$.

Comment: Okay, so with in this point you mean, leading coeff with respect to $\delta $? But I m still struggling. Why do we need this step?

Comment: @Chris Yes, leading coefficient with respect to $\delta$ (since you've written $\alpha$ as a polynomial with respect to $\delta$). As for why we need this step, did you read the rest of my argument? To conclude $\alpha$ has no $x$s in it, I'm supposing otherwise and reaching a contradiction. (I'm sure there's a different argument that involves looking at $\alpha x=x\alpha$ first, but I chose to look at $\alpha \delta=\delta\alpha$ first. We only "need" the step in my chosen route.)